# How to install oddjob-mkhomedir repository on AMI box using command line

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, yum, repository

I'm trying to install `oddjob-mkhomedir` and it comes back with no package available nothing to do. I used `sudo yum install oddjob-mkhomedir`
so I'm assuming the repository is not available.

My question is if the repository is indeed missing, where would I find it and how would I add it? Next would be how would I `install oddjob-mkhomedir?`

I found [this page](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/limit/1/srodzaj/1/dl/40/search/oddjob-mkhomedir/field%5B%5D/1/field%5B%5D/2), but I'm not sure that it is correct

Comment: That page is for the Fedora version so it's not what you want. You want the CentOS version of this package.

Comment: I don't have immediate access to a RHEL box right now but you might try to see if the package name is just different. It's a core part of the OS so it's definitely in the base channel. You don't need to get fancy.

Comment: @Bratchley, thanks, I hate to do this, but could you try to explain this a little bit more? This is my first linux project, so I'm extremely green and don't fully understand all the lingo

Comment: Some questions, is AMI based on CentOS? again I know nothing about linux. Is CentOS the free version of redhat? Are you thinking that package might just be named differently in CentOS, so just not oddjob?

Comment: AMI is just the name for amazon's OS images. [Looks like there is a CentOS AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00A6KUVBW/ref=mkt_ste_l2_ec2_f1?nc2=h_l3_c) you'd have to check what image your instance is running.

Comment: [Pick the version of RHEL you're running and download the CentOS version](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/). If you're on a RHEL image and haven't done too much it might be worth it to just switch to CentOS.

Comment: @Bratchley, Thanks That's exactly what I ended up doing last night. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm an Amazon AWS customer and I found the simplest solution was to move away from Amazons home grown AMI version and to install the latest version of CentOS. After migrating to CentOS, the missing dependencies we're no longer a factor.